# How in Visual Studio Code to use a regular expression to find a specific variable which has a number and replace that number to be a string

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my project, I have a situation in that some specific variables are assigned to numbers, but due to requirements, I have to change the numbers to a string.

For example, my original variable is like

```
question: 123
```

And I want to change it to

```
question: '123'
```

However, the var name is always the same what changes is the number so the match should be like

where `question:` check if the **number** has **''** if not add around the number the **''**

I was wishing for a regular expression for it as I have so many variables to change that manually is not easy, but I'm not good with RegEx

I'm also open to different suggestions if any no need mandatory a RegEx if there is a better solution to my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as following:

1. Press Ctrl + H on Windows and Linux, or ⌥⌘F on Mac to enable the search and replace tool.
2. Press the `.*` button to enable regex
3. In the search field you can type the regex : `question: ([0-9]+)`
4. In the replace field you can type : `question: '$1'`
5. And replace all

Each occurence of `question: <ANY NUMBER>` will be replaced by `question: '<ANY NUMBER>'`